# Как исправить ошибку: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем ошибка новичку)
У меня есть Набор данных (time series). Это таблица из двух колонок в первой из которых дата, а во второй значение индексу Dow Jones. 
Вот ссылка на csv с данными: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rrHVmywop5vEc6wIo73u0lTS4HU9rTT_ . Возможно, ошибка там

Запускаю код:

```
data = pd.read_csv('DJIA.csv', header=0)

# prepare data
X = data.values
X = X.astype('float32')
train_size = int(len(X) * 0.50)
train, test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
# walk-forward validation
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()
for i in range(len(test)):
    # predict
    yhat = history[-1]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    # observation
    obs = test[i]
    history.append(obs)
    print('>Predicted=%.3f, Expected=%3.f' % (yhat, obs))
# report performance
mse = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
rmse = sqrt(mse)
print('RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

Выдает 2 ошибки:

Первая ошибка:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-2ae5feb1d820> in <module>
      1 # prepare data
      2 X = data.values
----> 3 X = X.astype('float32')
      4 train_size = int(len(X) * 0.50)
      5 train, test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2009-07-23'
```

Вторая ошибка вознимает, когда удаляю строку X = X.astype('float32'):

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-dccb70d2484a> in <module>
     13         obs = test[i]
     14         history.append(obs)
---> 15         print('>Predicted=%.3f, Expected=%3.f' % (yhat, obs))
     16 # report performance
     17 mse = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Почеу возникают эти ошибки и как их исправить?)
Спасибо)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

1. Ошибка: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2009-07-23'` возникает потому, что Numpy не знает как преобразовать строку `'2009-07-23'` во `float32`
2. Ошибка: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` возникает потому, что вы хотите вывести скалярное число с плавающей точкой (`%.3f`), а передаете в качестве параметра Numpy Array в строке: `print('>Predicted=%.3f, Expected=%3.f' % (yhat, obs))`

   ```
   In [14]: yhat
   Out[14]: array(['2014-07-23', '17086.63'], dtype=object)

   In [15]: obs
   Out[15]: array(['2019-07-22', '27171.90'], dtype=object)
   ```

   ---

Можно преобразовать дату в целое число (число секунд прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`):

```
In [16]: data = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\DJIA.csv", parse_dates=["DATE"])

In [17]: data.head(3)
Out[17]:
        DATE     DJIA
0 2009-07-23  9069.29
1 2009-07-24  9093.24
2 2009-07-27  9108.51

In [18]: data.dtypes
Out[18]:
DATE    datetime64[ns]
DJIA            object
dtype: object

In [19]: data["DATE64"] = data["DATE"].astype("int64") // 10**9

In [20]: data.head(5)
Out[20]:
        DATE     DJIA      DATE64
0 2009-07-23  9069.29  1248307200
1 2009-07-24  9093.24  1248393600
2 2009-07-27  9108.51  1248652800
3 2009-07-28  9096.72  1248739200
4 2009-07-29  9070.72  1248825600
```