# Как заполнить нужные строки средними средним арифметическим соседних двух строк?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть ДатаФрейм - таймсерия. Кое-какие значения в дата фрейме отсутствуют, а на их месте стоит '.'

Я хочу заменить все значения с '.' на среднее апрфметическое двух соседних значений  колонки

Возможен так же вариант, что два или ти соседние значения принимают '.'. Т. е. для исчисления показателей надо брать не соседние, а соседние значения, которые не ровняются '.'
Подскажите пжл как это сделать

Пример входных данных:

```
DJIA

3

.

5

6
```

Пример выходных данных:

```
DJIA

3

4

5

6
```

где 4 = (3+5)/2

Пробую вот так:

```
for i in data['DJIA']:
    if i == '.':
        data['DJIA'][i] = (data['DJIA'][i-1] + data['DJIA'][i+1])/2
```

Здесь ошибка очевидна:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-0eabe272e58d> in <module>
      1 for i in data['DJIA']:
      2     if i == '.':
----> 3         data['DJIA'][i] = (data['DJIA'][i-1] + data['DJIA'][i+1])/2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Как правильно реализовать этот функционал?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных и выходных (то что хотите получить на выходе). [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU добавлено

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\DJIA.csv", na_values=["."], parse_dates=["DATE"])
data["DJIA"] = data["DJIA"].interpolate()
```

---

Пример для [данных из вашего предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1006199/211923):

```
In [18]: data.loc[110:130]
Out[18]:
          DATE      DJIA
110 2009-12-24  10520.10
111 2009-12-25       NaN
112 2009-12-28  10547.08
113 2009-12-29  10545.41
114 2009-12-30  10548.51
115 2009-12-31  10428.05
116 2010-01-01       NaN
117 2010-01-04  10583.96
118 2010-01-05  10572.02
119 2010-01-06  10573.68
120 2010-01-07  10606.86
121 2010-01-08  10618.19
122 2010-01-11  10663.99
123 2010-01-12  10627.26
124 2010-01-13  10680.77
125 2010-01-14  10710.55
126 2010-01-15  10609.65
127 2010-01-18       NaN
128 2010-01-19  10725.43
129 2010-01-20  10603.15
130 2010-01-21  10389.88

In [19]: data["DJIA"] = data["DJIA"].interpolate()

In [20]: data.loc[110:130]
Out[20]:
          DATE       DJIA
110 2009-12-24  10520.100
111 2009-12-25  10533.590
112 2009-12-28  10547.080
113 2009-12-29  10545.410
114 2009-12-30  10548.510
115 2009-12-31  10428.050
116 2010-01-01  10506.005
117 2010-01-04  10583.960
118 2010-01-05  10572.020
119 2010-01-06  10573.680
120 2010-01-07  10606.860
121 2010-01-08  10618.190
122 2010-01-11  10663.990
123 2010-01-12  10627.260
124 2010-01-13  10680.770
125 2010-01-14  10710.550
126 2010-01-15  10609.650
127 2010-01-18  10667.540
128 2010-01-19  10725.430
129 2010-01-20  10603.150
130 2010-01-21  10389.880
```

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется сделать так просто, как то, что приводит к ошибке, то надо немного усложнить другую часть кода

```
for i in range(len(data['DJIA'])):
    if data['DJIA'][i] == '.':
        data['DJIA'][i] = (data['DJIA'][i-1] + data['DJIA'][i+1])/2
```